# How can I create a firewall containing a ban system with Apache?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

I have a home server exposed to the internet, and host some services such as Nextcloud and Gitea for friends. However, there are people I'd like to keep out of my network via an IP ban. How can I have a virtual host sit between the services and the internet, check incoming connections against a ban list, and accordingly redirect to the site the user or app tried to access if the check fails? In case the check passes, showing the user a "banned" page, even if I need to write a Node.js app for it would be preferable, but not needed, simply timing them out is fine.

Comment: Google "Fail2Ban". Don't reinvent the wheel, fail2ban works fine. https://securitylab.github.com/research/Fail2exploit/

Comment: Why does it have to be done "with Apache"? Regular firewalls like iptables can already drop connections of any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gantendo mentioned in his comment, fail2ban is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

I used the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68209797/ to create a permanent jail in the file `/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/recidive.conf`:

```
[recidive]
enabled = true
logpath = /var/log/fail2ban.log
banaction = %(banaction_allports)s
bantime = -1        ; permanent
findtime = 86400    ; 1 day
maxretry = 6
```

and manually added IPs to it using the command `sudo fail2ban-client set recidive banip <IP_ADDRESS>`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't seem like I can accept a comment, so I thought I'd reference it and mark my own answer as accepted, which I can only do in 2 days.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but a big part of SU is that the answers should help both the person asking the question AND others who will have the same question/problem. This post conveys some basic information, but is not an answer because it isn't enough information to describe what you did, or to help anyone else.